# HTML DIVS expanding with content dynamically?

Tags: html, css

i have inside the body main 'container' div and inside this 'container' div there are three divs which are ,'header', 'content' and 'footer' my question is, i want the 'content' div to expand vertically with content increasing dynamically and by that the 'footer' will be pushed down when 'content' div is expanding. and all of this is done inside the main 'container' div so it also expand vertically!?

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
      <title>Untitled Page</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
     <div id="container">
         <div id="header"></div>
         <div id="content"></div>
         <div id="footer"></div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    background-color:Gray;
}
#container
{
    border: dotted;
}
#content
{
    border:dotted;
}
#header
{
    border:dotted;    
}
#footer
{
    border:dotted;
}
```

Comment: Please revise your question's title. People will have a hard time know what your after. Also please try to explain further what you're trying to achieve. It sounds to me that all you need is a basic functionality and don't have to do anything to get this working? http://jsfiddle.net/p5Jvj/ — Does this look like what you're after?

Comment: The you have it set-up, it should work as you want.. nothing more to do ..

Comment: thank u, but also i need to be initially at fixed size and if it is exceeded then expand and move the footer down as well as the contained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the CSS attribute `min-height` for this purpose, but you'll have to consider that it won't be support in all (legacy) browsers.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YS9XV/1/

Answer (score 0):

That is how things will behave unless you tell them otherwise.

(Don't set a height on anything, that is the key 'otherwise' for this type of thing, (if you think you want to, then look to min-height instead).)

Comment: so if initially i want to be at cretin height and whenever the content increased, should i use min height to specify that minimum height i want??

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for: http://wildreason.com/images/liquid-layout-css.png

The two columns in the center will maintain respective heights as one or the other expands vertically.